# Which PHP hosting is better GoDaddy or 1and1? and Also domain mangement

Tags: domains, web-hosting, dns, compatibility, 1and1

I own a domain on GoDaddy and I bought a hosting plan from 1and1. Now my subscription is going to end and I want to renew it, but I also want to choose only one company for my web site to have both the domain and the hosting plan.

I'm hosting a Wordpress Blog System.

Which company would you prefer/recommend, and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend just about any cPanel hosting provider over GoDaddy or 1and1 - cPanel is a hosting industry standard and is **far** easier to use than GoDaddy or 1and1's custom hosting management interfaces (at least, that was the case when I last had to work with either - about four years ago).

Presently hosting with HostGator.

Comment: I think I might go for HostGator or DreamHost

Comment: I use hostmonster, they have amazing support!

Answer (score 1):

Do not purchase anything from 1and1. I had a VPS with them many years ago and many things went wrong, all of which were setup flaws on 1and1's part. Their customer service is terrible and only available during certain hours. Not to be racist but they outsource their call-in-reps so you will almost never speak with an american. I purchased another vps with them last month and ran into the same issues. I quickly remembered why I changed to godaddy.

Godaddy doesnt have a very intuitive interface at all, but the customer service rocks. After you get around learning the admin panel it isnt bad.

I dont have experience with host gator.

any hosting that offers cpanel and has been above recommended is fine. If they dont have cpanel then it really isnt worth investing in.

Answer (score 0):

GoDaddy isn't very great for developing products as far as I've used it. I'm currently looking for alternatives as well.
I have a hard time getting around goDaddy's interface. I've used a few other services like Bluehost, enom, and register.com, those are actually easier to use than GoDaddy.
I have **not** used 1and1.

Comment: I've used GoDaddy for domain registration and web hosting before and it was kinda good. But what's the GoDaddy interface that you mentioned before?

Comment: Give DreamHost a try. I've used them, GoDaddy, and a few other web hosts and registrars, and DreamHost has the best customer service and value for shared hosting. I haven't tried their VPS service yet, but they also have that if you need it. And if you google for DreamHost coupons, you can get $100 off of your first year of hosting.

Comment: I'm thinking of going over to Dreamhost because I've heard good things about them. @Pr0fess0rX, I've used goDaddy's total DNS control and it just doesn't work as quick as others like eNom's. And it's often hard to navigate through their dashboard. But I think I'm just used to others that's why.

Comment: I disagree with you about GoDaddy's Total DNS I saw it so easy and the update goes fast but I didn't try eNom to decide which is faster!

Comment: Since that answer, you have good alternatives, like gandi.net or Google domains. Avoid register.com (pita).